# How to change the hierarchy of annotations in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I might be blind but I don't find the possibility to change the hierarchy of "Annotations" in the Preferences of eclipse.

My problem is that warnings, which are displayed as yellow bars, hide "write occurrences" at the same line. Is there an easy way to move warnings to the lowest graphical level?

To be more verbose:
If I selected a variable and it is written to in a line were also a warning is, then the "write occurrences" mark is invisible as it is fully covered by the "warning" mark.

I don't want to switch off the warnings, I just would prefer them to have lower priority.

PS.: A "complex" way is also appreciated.

Comment: Please explain with more words? what u would say here.

Comment: ok, I added a "verbose" section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is anything to control the priority but you can turn off the warnings display in the 'overview' ruler (the right hand ruler).

Go to `Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations` and select the `Warnings` annotation. You can then uncheck the `Overview ruler` option.

Update:
The `org.eclipse.ui.editors.markerAnnotationSpecification` extension point sets the 'layer' used for the warning annotation (and other markers types). There does not appear to be any way to override this.

Comment: I found that but I thought there might be a possibility to change instead of switching off.

Comment: Added a bit about where the hierarchy is defined, but this doesn't help with changing it.

Comment: Thanks. I presume `presentationLayer` is responsible so nothing to do it seems (except patching and recompiling).